# html page hanging when posting file upload

Tags: php, html, post, mime, enctype

I'm trying to add a file upload script in php to a website I'm designing. I've used an online example (I know it's not secure and I plan on making it secure, I just want the basic functionality working first).

Basically what's happening is that when I click the "submit" button, the page stalls and says "loading xyz server.." forever and doesn't ever go to the post action php page! This is very frustrating and I can't see why it won't work!

The code is below and I've tried this on 2 different servers with same results. I'd be very grateful if someone could let me know what I'm possibly doing wrong?

```
<html> 
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="do.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>


<?php
//Сheck that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
    ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)) {
    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
?>
```

Thanks very much for your time, I have searched for hours to fix this with no luck!

Comment: Maybe it's a really big file and you're waiting for it to upload? Did you take a look at your PC's network usage meter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! It turns out it was something to do with the wireless network at my University. I got home, refreshed the page and it worked fine. I will have to have words with the system administrator about the time I wasted trying to solve a problem made by them.

Thanks for the help anyway guys,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

If you post to an Iframe it won't lock your page. Then watch the Iframe contents to see what the server response is, or better: use Firebug on Firefox and inspect he NET tab to see what's going on with your post request.

Comment: I don't know how to use iFrames because I've been told they're terrible but I just tried and it simply won't post to anything. Even if the post action is "" it still hangs. I've never used FireBug so I'm not really sure what I'm looking for but if I refresh the page, Firebug shows that this POST was aborted and shows that it was just waiting for ages. DNS lookup and sending were fine but waiting was 20 seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Iframes, just as they're nothing wrong with Tables. Each tool has a purpose. You need to output some intermediate debug information to the browser as your upload is processed. Also, look at your server logs there may be a clue.

Answer (score 0):

How big of a file are you uploading? Most browsers do not display any kind of upload progress bar, and only recently has PHP supported even bare bones progress reports. For a large file, all you'd see is the "... loading ..." status bar text with no indication that data's actually being uploaded.

As for the rest of the code, here's a few things you need to clean up before putting this into production:

```
$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0
```

This will evaluate to true if the ['error'] element isn't set. Use `===` instead, which does forces value and type to be equal, not merely value.

```
if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") &&
```

The filename and filetype values in the $_FILES array are what's supplied by the remote user, and can be easily mainipulated. Best to use a server-side mime-type identifer (`getimagesize()` for pictures works well) to see what the file really is.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips :)
But the file size is 10k (a tiny image)